# Swift UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

For some reason, I can't get my gesture recognizer to work. The following line of code is executed in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.segmentTapped(sender:))))
```

The following is the method associated with the gesture:

```
 func segmentTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("called")
 }
```

When the code is executed, "called" does not print in the console when the view is tapped. Gesture recognizers have always worked for me in the past, and I am confused as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Make sure `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I actually already did that, but I forgot to include it in the question.

Comment: Okay, try replacing `sender: UITapGestureRecognizer` (function parameter) with `_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer` and `#selector(self.segmentTapped(sender:))` with `#selector(self.segmentTapped(_:))`  other than that, it should have worked

Comment: Rehaan, your code is working just fine for me. I believe there might be something interfering with the `UITapGestureRecognizer`. However, I'm not entirely sure what since I don't know what your program is doing on that specific view.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you everyone who tried to help! The solution to this problem was quite simple. I simply deleted the app, reinstalled it, and the tap gesture worked as intended.